# How to handle the equality constraint that cannot be satisfied?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

Given an optimization problem
$$
\text{min}  \space x^T M x \\
\text{s.t.} \space Ax = b
$$
where an analytical solution called **weighted general inverse** exists.
However, we now know that Ax = b some times cannot be satisfied because A becomes singular.
In this case, how can I still write the above problem as a solvable convex optimization (QP)?

Currently, I am thinking of
$$
\text{min}  \space w_1x^T M x +w_2(Ax - b)^T(Ax - b)\\
\text{where } w_2 >> w_1
$$
However, this will cause the solution to be less accurate when A is not Singular.
Is there any way to re-write this?

Answer (score 1):

Assume $x = x_r+x_n$ where $x_r\in \text{Range}\left(A\right)$ and $x_n\in \text{Null}\left(A\right)$. Then we have

$$
\text{min}  \space \left(x_r+x_n\right)^T M \left(x_r+x_n\right) \\
\text{s.t.} \space Ax_r = b\\
 \quad \space Ax_n = 0
$$

Is this okay?! You can write Lagrangian now.